# Best practice for specifying number of new lines in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Since long I am using this for specifying new line and it works fine.

```
(?:.*[\r\n]+){n,m}
```

Is this the best practice for doing this?

Comment: no, it should be `(?:.*\r?\n){n,m}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `(?:.*\r?\n){n,m}` since `[\r\n]+` in your regex should match one or more newline chars greedily. So it won't do the exact work you want.

Comment: It increases number of steps in regex101 tester. Is number of steps has anything to do with speed?

Comment: first check for the functionality and then test the speed.

Comment: OK. I also believe that accuracy should come first and then speed. Looks like people uses the same.